# socket.io - listen on multiple namespaces with one packet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

We are migrating from APE to socket.io. So far, so good, but... is there way to join multiple namespaces with one packet? I've tried something like that:

```
websocket received data packet 1::/public,/foo,/bar,/baz
```

but that doesn't work. What is best way to achieve that?

**Edit:**

Ok, it seems that packet works, problem lies on server end. Is there way to intercept all namespaces with on('connection')? We have dynamically created namespaces, so there is no possibility for us to include them all on server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on Socket.io mailing group that it is technically possible, but it's much better to use rooms feature, and I did that in that way.